# Java interfaces - CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to really understand how those Interfaces in Java work. 
As I know, it's kinda used to describe what implementing classes will do but not how to do that. That's clear enough for me.

The problem is, when I try to use `CrudRepository` interface from Spring Data package, then I don't really know how it works.
I create for example `CarRepository` which extends `CrudRepository` interface without adding any new methods.
After this I create `CarService` class which injects `CarRepository` via `CarService` constructor for dependency Injection.

Regarding to that I use `save` method from `CarRepository` and I am totally lost because I don't know, how it's possible that it's really saving the passed object to the database. The reason is, that this `save` method has no 'body', so that how does it know, how to insert to to the database?

The example of the code:

```
class CarService{
     private CarRepository carRepository;
     public CarService(CarRepository carRepository){
           this.carRepository = carRepository;}

     public Car saveCar(Car car){
     Car savedCar = carRepository.save(car);
     return savedCar;

}


}
}
```

Can you guys please clarify me, how is that possible that this method saves the car object to the any database configured to the spring? Cuz there is no body of `save` method, so how does it know how to do that?

Comment: It's not at all related how interfaces work in Java. It is about the magic done behind the scenes by `spring.data`

Comment: also: if you don't know how interfaces work, don't use frameworks yet, but study the basics.

Comment: From the description, it sounds like Spring is creating a class from your CRUD interface at runtime? Try to log or print the value of carRepository.getClass().getName(); it will probably be something like `CGLib$something` or `Javassist$something`, indicating that they were dynamically created via either CGLib or Javassist.

Answer (score 3):

It is functionality provided by Spring Data. Under the hood, Spring will determine which database you are trying to use. Say you are using the SQL database PostgreSQL. Spring determines it should use the appropriate interface `JpaRepository`. Then Spring Data JPA, one of the many Spring Data sub-modules, will provide the basic implementation for `JpaRepository`.

Spring is also able to dynamically provide implementations for any custom queries you've declared in `CarRepository`. However, for this to work, the declared methods need to follow specific naming conventions. For example, Spring is able to understand the method

```
List<Car> findByName(String name);
```

which will retrieve all `Car`s by parameter `name`, but not

```
List<Car> pleaseGiveAllCarsWithName(String name);
```

For the method naming conventions, please see the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details).

It is because of these provided implementations by Spring that basic methods such as `save` but also custom defined queries such as `findByName` will work "out of the box".

Comment: Alright. So if I'd declare any additional method to CarRepository which is not overriding any method from CrudRepository interface, then I guess it won't be managed by all this Spring features?
For example I'd add a method to a CarRepository:
public String showCarBrand(Car car);

so that it wouldn't know what to do with that?

Comment: @MaciejPapurzyński Yes indeed, you cannot add arbitrary methods to a repository interface, because Spring Data won't know how to generate an implementation for such methods. The method has to have a specific signature (see [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)) which Spring Data understands.

Comment: Updated my answer to include the custom query topic and documentation link by @Jesper

Answer (score 3):

Normally, to be able to use an interface in a Java application, you will also need at least one non-abstract class that implements the interface - otherwise there is indeed nothing to execute when you call a method.

Spring Data works with interfaces in a different way than what you would do in a "normal" Java program. It looks at your repository interface, and then automatically generates a class that implements the interface when you run the program. When you call methods on the repository interface, what's actually executed is the code in that automatically generated class.

You never get to see the actual class, because it's generated dynamically, when you run the program - it doesn't yet exist when you write and compile the code.

This way of working is very powerful, and it's what makes Spring Data so nice to work with. You don't have to write all the tedious code for working with the database yourself - you only have to define an interface which specifies what exactly you want to get out of the database, and Spring Data will automatically generate all the code for you.